In VS Code Source control repo there is showing 10000+ changes
Screenshot of vs code
i want to remove these changes from vs code. There is one folder in my c file where all my directories are created. All files from this folder are in the changes. I tried unstaging all changes and also deleting it but it's not possible.

Be sure you're in the right branch so you don't commit your entire operating system. A screenshot of your file structure will help understand the issue.

You're going to want the files but also remove them from source control. This has already been asked here => Remove a file from a Git repository without deleting it from the local filesystem

This question is similar to: Remove a file from a Git repository without deleting it from the local filesystem. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
